AWS Notebook: ClientError: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
I had this error while trying to read a csv file from s3 bucket
import pandas as pd

bucket='bucket-name'
data_key = 'OGTDv1.csv'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)

pd.read_csv(data_location)

Thats my code. I want to load the csv file. I also tried to off the Block all public access

The IAM role attached to your notebook instance needs IAM permission to the specific bucket you are trying to read/download from. Take a look at the docs for more details on Policies and Permissions in Amazon S3

If the bucket is in a different account the you will need to configure cross account access.
